# ExpressJS: Getting associated posts, comments for a page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redux

Assume that I am trying to build a blog. Each `Page` has many `Posts` and each `Post` has many `Comments`.
I am trying to return the following JSON output from a Express/Mongo Server.

```
page: {
  _id: <page_id>
  title: "page title"
  posts: [Post],
  comments: [Comment] // *Q2. notice comments are not nested under posts.
}
```

This is what I tried

```
.get((req, res) => {
  Page.findOne({title: req.params.title}, (err, page) => {
    if (err) { return res.json(err) }
    if (!page) { return res.json({error: "doesnt exist"}) }

    Post.find({page: page._id})
      .populate({ path: 'author'})
      .exec((err, posts) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err)
        }

        const postIds = posts.map(post => post._id)
        Comment.find({post: {$in: postIds}}, (comments => {

          // FIXME
          res.json(Object.assign({},
            page.toObject(),
            posts,
            comments
          ))
        }))
      })
  })
})
```

I have several questions.

Q1. How come I am not getting the expected output with the following?

```
          res.json(Object.assign({},
            page.toObject(),
            posts,
            comments
          ))
```

Q2. I am making three different queries to return data for a single page. Is this against the convention or very inefficient? Do people usually do it this way? (I am not embedding comments documents inside post documents on purpose)

Q3 (Optional). I decided to return `posts` and `comments` in a *normalized* format so that the frontend can easily make a state tree (Redux recommends normalized app state tree). Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: You're mixing a bunch of different things to make an unholy concoction. Posts and comments are an array, but the page is not. The `Object.assign(...)` takes all the properties of those things and puts them together on a target object.

You'll want something like:

```
Object.assign({}, page.toObject, {
  posts: posts.map(p => p.toObject()),
  comments: comments.map(c => c.toObject())
});
```

Q2: Mongo is a document store and it's perfectly fine to make 3 queries. That said, you could store the comments inside the post document and need only 1 query per post. Denormalization is the norm for document / k/v / object stores.

Q3: No. That's fine. Redux with `normalizr` likes it better. That said, Redux philosophy dictates that you must always do whatever you think is best.